# Pseudo Inverse of product of Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, pseudoinverse

Let $A$ and $B$ are two matrices where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times p}$ and $B \in \mathbb{R}^{p\times n}$ and both $A$ and $B$ are full rank matrices  Now I really want to know in what cases

$(AB)^+ = B^+A^+$  ,where $A^+$ is Moore-Penrose Pseudo-inverse of $A$

Here $m,p$ and $n$ are in any order like $m<p<d$ or $m>p<d$ etc.

Comment: See [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore–Penrose_pseudoinverse#Products)

Comment: Can this be extended to a product of three matrices ?
For instance, can you say  $(ABC)^{+} =
 C^+ B^+ A^ +$
Where $A,B$ and $C$ are matrices of the appropriate sizes.  Will this hold if A and C are rectangular matrices ?

Answer (score 12):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_pseudoinverse#Products)

[image: products]

### Example

#### Define matrices

$$
\mathbf{A} = 
\left[
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 1 \\
 3 & 2 \\
 0 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right]
, \quad
%
\mathbf{B} =
\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & 3 & 0 \\
 1 & 2 & 2 \\
\end{array}
\right]
, \quad
%
\mathbf{C} = \mathbf{A} \mathbf{B} =
\left[
\begin{array}{rrr}
 1 & 2 & 2 \\
 2 & 13 & 4 \\
 2 & 4 & 4 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$
$$
\mathbf{A}^{\dagger} = \frac{1}{15}
\left[
\begin{array}{rrr}
 -2 & 5 & -4 \\
 3 & 0 & 6 \\
\end{array}
\right]
, \quad
%
\mathbf{B}^{\dagger} = \frac{1}{15}
\left[
\begin{array}{rr}
 -2 & 3 \\
 5 & 0 \\
 -4 & 6 \\
\end{array}
\right]
, \quad
%
\mathbf{C}^{\dagger} = \frac{1}{225}
\left[
\begin{array}{rrr}
 13 & -10 & 26 \\
 -10 & 25 & -20 \\
 26 & -20 & 52 \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

#### Test premise

Does $\mathbf{C}^{\dagger} = \mathbf{B}^{\dagger}\mathbf{A}^{\dagger}$?
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbf{B}^{\dagger}\mathbf{A}^{\dagger} &= \frac{1}{15}
\left[
\begin{array}{rr}
 -2 & 3 \\
  5 & 0 \\
 -4 & 6 \\
\end{array}
\right]
\frac{1}{15}
\left[
\begin{array}{rrr}
 -2 & 5 & -4 \\
 3 & 0 & 6 \\
\end{array}
\right] \\[3pt]
%%
& =
%%
\frac{1}{225}
\left[
\begin{array}{rrr}
 13 & -10 & 26 \\
 -10 & 25 & -20 \\
 26 & -20 & 52 \\
\end{array}
\right] \\
&= \mathbf{C}^{\dagger}
\end{align}
$$

#### Conclusion

$$\therefore \qquad \left(\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}\right)^{\dagger} = \mathbf{B}^{\dagger}\mathbf{A}^{\dagger}$$

Comment: I was wondering about what that "equivalent" symbol meant. So, does that $(AB)^+ \equiv B^+A^+$ actually mean $(AB)^+ = B^+A^+$?

Comment: @Hilder Vitor Lima Pereira. Yes, think of it as an equality. The explanation has been rewritten to avoid ambiguity.